# I am facing ConditionalCheckFailedException while performing update operation on table in dynamoDB using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create fake audience app using coveritlive chat system. For this i have created different lambda functions one for posting comments, one for getting item id and one for adding reply to comment.
But for implementing reply service i need to get item_id of comment which i can get by calling event/data API of coveritlive.com.
But am getting following exception while performing update operation in Amazon DynamoDB. I don't know why this exception is being shown. Also i want to know if there is any bulk update functionality available or not. Please help me in resolving this issue.

```
ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27) at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20) at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:
06179d64-8906-11e8-bc53-f1cb2c5efa4e    { ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
message: 'The conditional request failed',
code: 'ConditionalCheckFailedException',
requestId: 'JVQV9VI69F3T2UDG6388RLDPFBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 4.294909454040329
```

This is the code i am using for updation:

```
function updateItemId(id,itemId,docClient) {
    var updateParams = {
        TableName:"comments",
        Key: {
            Id : Number(id)
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set ItemId = :ItemId",
        ConditionExpression: "ItemId = :x",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":ItemId":Number(itemId),
            ":x":0
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };
    docClient.update(updateParams,function(err,data){
        if(err) {
           console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to replace ItemId by calling it frequently.

Comment: it just means that no such key exists in database, so the conditional request is failing.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the "ItemId" does not equal 0 in the item which matches the key, so it'll throw an exception named `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

If why there is no match doesn't matter, all you need to do is to catch and ignore it.

```
if (err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
    // nerver mind.
}
```